# Mistake in Cover Letter

Tags: resume, job-search, cover-letter

Before asking my question I searched this site and came across these two ([1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32301/interview-should-i-admit-to-a-typo-on-my-resume),[2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58700/how-to-handle-a-deal-breaking-mistake-in-a-cover-letter-or-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9)) pages that are similar to my problem, but also slightly different. It's not the misspelling of a word or stating the incorrect company name.

I'm currently job searching and applying to many jobs that have similar responsibilities, so I constructed a personal cover letter template with the following line:

```
I'm interested in applying for insert job title here.
```

I copied the job title and pasted it into my template, but I noticed this mistake:

```
I'm interested in applying for insert Data Entry Coordinator.
```

**after** I sent in my cover letter.

I've read [other sites](https://www.levo.com/posts/cover-letter-mistakes) and [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/58712/85194), that cover letters rarely get read and mistakes such as typos will get ignored unless it's for a writing position, my problem is, there is some indication that the cover letter will be read, because the job posting indicated I'm supposed provide my salary expectations.

**Question:**
Should I just move on and expect my resume/cover letter will be ignored?

**Afterwards:**

I saved my template in a text file so there was no special formatting or font color to indicate that line should be adjusted. I've corrected the problem by saving the template in another format, with red font, and yellow highlighting, so I'm more aware of what text has to be changed.

**Edit:** My problem doesn't "dramatically change perception". If anything, the above two links provided have more in common with my question, but as stated it's slightly different.

Comment: You seem to be looking for an answer that fits your situation down to the letter - that somewhat undermines the principle of a Q&A site. The posts you and I linked does appear to me to answer your question - they say cover letters rarely get read and are often skimmed over, your experience is more important and there isn't much you can do about it after you've sent it. All of those things are 100% applicable here. The post I linked is a more severe problem, yes, but yet the advice given is still that there isn't much to be done (which obviously also then applies in less severe cases).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Question: Should I just move on

Yes. What's done is done. The only option you have would be sending an updated cover letter. This may help or make it worse. You really don't know which, so I'd just let it be.

> and expect my resume/cover letter will be ignored?

No. This is not the end of the world and it may go undetected or ignored or many people may just find it funny and human (which it is). It's a ding on your "attention to detail" score, but depending on culture and job this may not be a major problem. I wouldn't just give up because of that. Worst that can happen is they say "thanks, but no thanks". No harm in following up just the same way you would do with any other application